# How to merge few 3D JSON objects in JS [or jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I have to merge 2 (up to 6) JSON objects.

I got this code: **http://jsfiddle.net/5Uz27/**

But with this code, I can only merge the first level of the objects, so the deeper levels are usually overwritten. Check the output.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery.extend(true, original_object, extend_with);

source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you can use `$.extend()` to do a "deep"/recursive merge of objects, by passing in `true` as the first argument.

Here's how this might work in your example:

```
// turn the strings into objects
var pref_array = $.map(json_holder, JSON.parse);
// add the deep=true argument
pref_array.unshift(true);
// now do a deep extend, passing the array as arguments
var prefs = $.extend.apply(null, pref_array );
```

This might be a little obtuse (you could make it even more so, but tighter, by setting `pref_array` to `[true].concat($.map(json_holder, JSON.parse))`), but it avoids the ungainly `for` loop (that might be personal preference, I suppose).

Working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/e6bnU/